# Initializing a dataframe to contain `Date` and `decimal`

Tags: r

I want to initialize a dataframe that contains as rows: `Date`, `integer`, `integer`, and `decimal`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
df = data.frame(Date = date(), a = integer(0), b = integer(0), ratio = numeric(0.0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error in data.frame(Date = date(), a = integer(0), b = integer(0), ratio = numeric(0),  :
```

arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

When I remove the `Date = date()` part, I no longer have this error.

I also tried:

```
df = data.frame(Date = date(0), a = integer(0), b = integer(0), ratio = numeric(0.0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This gave me the error:

```
Error in date(0) : unused argument (0)
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I initialize a `Date` in a dataframe?
2. How do I initialize a `decimal` in a dataframe? Is doing `numeric(0.0)` how you do it?

Comment: A few notes: (1) Almost never is convenient to initialize an empty "vector", "matrix", "data.frame", "list" etc. It's a good approach to pre-specify the type of data in your columns and it's even better to pre-allocate those columns (even with some "NA"s or something else neutral) and replace those values later than expandind your structure again and again. Searching SO a bit will get many hints on how to think more "R-ish".

Comment: (2) The `?function` paradigm is very helpful in understanding different R functions. `date` and `integer` are functions which means that each has its own arguments. Looking at `?date` there is none argument needed and the function outputs a "character vector of length 1". `date(0)` makes no sense because `date` takes no arguments at all. `?integer` (and `numeric`) on the other hand need one argument wich specifies the "length" of the outputted result; `integer(0)` outputs an "integer vector of length 0".

Comment: `numeric(0.0)` makes no different sense than `numeric(0)` since `numeric` takes one integer argument and if the argument is not "integer" it will coerce it to an integer if possible or output an error. (3) To explicitly use decimals you need `double`. Although `numeric` will give a "double", "numeric" is the class of both "integer"s and "double"s in R (e.g. `is.numeric(as.double(1))` and `is.numeric(as.integer(1))`). Generally, any number in R will be regarded as "double" unless specified somehow else (e.g. using `as.integer` or the suffix `L` (5L)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(character()), a = integer(), 
     b = integer(), ratio = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df)
#'data.frame':  0 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ Date :Class 'Date'  num(0) 
#$ a    : int 
#$ b    : int 
#$ ratio: num
```